# How to create left and right side inside container?

Tags: html, css

[image]What i have is sidebar and on right side i have content. What i want is that both sides are in container but that are both full width . This is my demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19067/

So i want that left background color start from beging of page but text inside is in container and also i want that background color of right content go to the end of page but text is in container. Any suggestion?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="left_sidebar">
   menu
  </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="right-content">
  content
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample image showing the wanted result?

Comment: sure... wait a sec

Comment: @Aides there i show u simple image

Comment: @None, something like this?https://jsfiddle.net/booz5p98/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x0vvm2zt/

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, wrap the colored containers above the `container` class and use two different containers:

```
<div class="left_sidebar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-3">
           menu
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right-content">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="col-md-9">
          content
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19069/)

*REMOVED other edits because EDIT 3 should do the trick best*

**EDIT 3**

Here it is, that must be it for sure now. The trick is done with a `linear gradient`and a custom container above your bootstrap container.

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19079/)

Comment: i need to have content in container

Comment: See my EDIT 2, hope this is what you wanted

Comment: hmm its not what i want.. i want one container

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking, is by default impossible, since the .container class has a set width on different viewports and it is also horizontally "centerised" by `margin:auto`.

To achieve what you are trying you will have to follow a different "logic".
I would propose something like this:

```
<div class="left-sidebar col-md-3">
   <div class="sidebar-menu col-xs-6 pull-right">
      menu
   </div>
</div>
<div class="right-content col-md-9>
   <div class="content-text col-xs-10>
      content
   </div>
</div>
```

I propse this solution in order to stay in the same "flow" as your code. You could also, just play with paddings, which makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

use class row before col div

```
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-md6"></div>
 <div class="col-md-6"><div>
</div>
```